# Is Optaplanner Strength Comparator compatible with Partitioning?

Tags: sorting, optaplanner, partitioner

Has anyone tried Optaplanner's Partitioned Search feature at the same time as the strength comparator class??

Firstly, I created a custom partitioner that splits the planning entities and assigns the planning values (it does not split the planning values since I need all of them for each partition). Which has worked fine until now.

Then I tried to implement a Planning Value strength and it seems to work out if I am not using the partitioner but the code stops running when I do.
Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Sounds like a bug, please create an issue (see issue tracker in "get help").